# Laravel кастомный класс

Tags: laravel, классы, laravel-8

На старом проекте использовался класс для работы с изображениями. Сейчас переношу все на ларавел. Я создал файл app/Library/Thumb.php. Подключаю класс в файл:

```
use App\Library\Thumb;
```

Использую:

```
$thumb = new Thumb($image->getPathName());
```

Весь класс вставлять не буду, ошибка появляется в конструкторе:

```
namespace App\Library;

class Thumb
{
    //public $filename, $width, $height, $type, $img;

    public function __construct($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        if (empty($this->filename)) {
            return 'Файл не найден';
        } else {
            $info = getimagesize($this->filename);
            if (empty($info)) {
                return 'Файл не найден';
            } else {
                $this->width  = $info[0];
                $this->height = $info[1];
                $this->type   = $info[2];
                switch ($this->type) {
                    case 1:
                        $this->img = imageCreateFromGif($this->filename);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $this->img = imageCreateFromJpeg($this->filename);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $this->img = imagecreatefrompng($this->filename);
                        imageAlphaBlending($this->img, true);
                        imageSaveAlpha($this->img, true);
                        break;
                    case 18:
                        $this->img = imageCreatefromWebp($this->filename);
                        break;
                    default:
                        return 'Формат файла не подерживается';
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При выполнении одной из функций:

```
imageCreateFromGif()
imageCreateFromJpeg()
imageCreateFromPng()

Call to undefined function App\Library\imageCreateFromPng()
```

Данные функции стандартные в PHP и я так понимаю ларавел пытается их найти в пространстве имен данного класса?
Если я убираю пространство имен из этого класса, я не могу его никуда подключить.
Подскажите как сделать правильно чтобы я мог данный класс использовать в любом контроллере?
Пробовал прописывать в composer.json и делать update, не получилось ничего.
Я уже много перегуглил информации о подключении своих классов, везде пишут прописать простарнство имен и класс будет работать. По сути он у меня и заработал, но вот эти стандартные функции PHP не работают.

Comment: Я бы предложил попробовать перед названием фунции поставить  `\\`. Если менялся сервер или PHP, можно ещё проверить наличие GD расширения.

Comment: Как вам написали выше, проверьте что подключено расширение GD, так как эти функции не стандартные, а часть этого расширения.